# Error when using nested navigators in react-navigation & FluidTransitions

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm confused on how to declare my nested react-navigation navigator.

So the structure I'm trying to make it is a set of screens in the BottomTabNavigator, and this BottomTabNavigator is in a FluidNavigator itself. Now, the HomeScreen is under BottomTabNavigator, but a child component in BottomTabNavigator is using [Fluid Transitions](https://github.com/fram-x/FluidTransitions)' Shared Element Transition. Due to this structure, I'm receiving the error:

> TypeError: expected dynamic type 'double', but had type 'null'

When I remove the tabs system, everything's working fine. So I guess something's wrong with the way I'm creating these Navigators.

Here's the structure I'm using:

```
> Fluid Navigator:
  > Home (Bottom Tab Navigator)
    > SharedScreenSource
    > Tab2
    > Tab3
  > SharedScreenDestination
```

Here's the current code for reference:

```
const HomeTabsNav = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
    Tab1WithSharedScreenComponent: { screen: Tab1, path: '/tab1' },
    Tab2: { screen: Tab2, path: '/tab2' },
    Tab3: { screen: Tab3, path: '/tab3' }
},
{ tabBarPosition: 'bottom', animationEnabled: false, swipeEnabled: false }
);

const RootStack = createFluidNavigator(
{
    Home: HomeTabsNav,
    SharedScreenDestination: SharedScreenDestination // this screen opens through Tab1's child component
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    mode: 'card',
    headerMode: 'none',
    navigationOptions: {
        header: null
    },
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct implementation method (that worked for me) is the following structure:

```
> FluidNavigator:
  > Home (Bottom Tab Navigator)
    > FluidNavigator2:
        > SharedScreenSource
        > SharedScreenDestination
    > Tab2
    > Tab3
  > OtherScreens...
```

And in code would translate to something like this:

```
const FluidNavigator2 = createFluidNavigator(
{
    SharedScreenSource: SharedScreenSource,
    SharedScreenDestination: SharedScreenDestination
},
{
    headerMode: 'none',
    navigationOptions: {
        header: null
    },
}
);

const HomeTabsNav = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
    Tab1WithSharedScreenComponent: { screen: FluidNavigator2, path: '/tab1' },
    Tab2: { screen: Tab2, path: '/tab2' },
    Tab3: { screen: Tab3, path: '/tab3' }
},
{ tabBarPosition: 'bottom', animationEnabled: false, swipeEnabled: false }
);

const RootStack = createFluidNavigator(
{
    Home: HomeTabsNav,
    OtherScreens: OtherScreens // this screen opens through Tab1's child component
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    mode: 'card',
    headerMode: 'none',
    navigationOptions: {
        header: null
    },
}
);
```

I'm not receiving the mentioned error anymore.